# Аномалия с отступами у карточки с картинкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

На скриншоте я показал неровности стрелками. Все остальные карточки нормальные. Так же когда выполняется поиск домов, этот аномальный участок смещается в другое место, а все остальные ведут себя как положено, почему такое поведение именно у этой карточки? Как исправить?[image: Аномалия]

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container-trading">
<div class="container-modal-row">
    <div class="modal-row-text">модельный ряд lofthaus</div>
    <div class="container-btn-params">
        <div class="btn-params-text">Подбор дома
            <div class="container-svg-icon-params">
                <svg></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  Modal window selection house  -->
    <div class="container-modal-window-selection-house">
        <button class="svg-icon-close-modal-window-selection-house">
            <svg></svg>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-window-selection-house">
            <div class="price-selection-house">цена, ₽</div>
            <div class="container-select-prices">
                <div class="input-label">
                    <div class="from-to">от</div>
                    <input class="input filter-input" type="number" placeholder="1 000 000" id="price-from">
                    <div class="filter-invalid-msg hidden-filter-invalid-msg">Введите цену от</div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-label">
                    <div class="from-to">до</div>
                    <input class="input filter-input" type="number" placeholder="15 000 000" id="price-to">
                    <div class="filter-invalid-msg hidden-filter-invalid-msg">Введите цену до</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="square-selection-house">площадь, м2</div>
            <div class="container-select-square">
                <div class="input-label">
                    <div class="from-to">от</div>
                    <input class="input filter-input" type="number" placeholder="50" id="area-from">
                    <div class="filter-invalid-msg hidden-filter-invalid-msg">Введите площадь от</div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-label">
                    <div class="from-to">до</div>
                    <input class="input filter-input" type="number" placeholder="250" id="area-to">
                    <div class="filter-invalid-msg hidden-filter-invalid-msg">Введите площадь до</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-btn-apply">
                <div class="btn-apply">Применить</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-btn-reset hidden-btn-reset">
                <div class="btn-reset">Сбросить</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  Modal window selection house  -->
</div>
<section class="container-items">
    <template>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="" alt="item-1">
        <div class="item-details">
            <div class="model-house"></div>
            <div class="container-info">
                <div class="price-house"></div>
                <div class="size-house"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-buttons">
                <div class="btn-more-detailed">
                    <div class="btn-style-more-detailed">Подробнее</div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-presentation">
                    <div class="btn-style-presentation">Презентация
                        <div class="container-svg-icon-pdf">
                            <svg></svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
</section>
<div class="container-show-all-houses">
    <button class="show-all-houses">+ Все дома</button>
</div>
<div class="no-results-message hidden-message">По вашему запросу дома не найдены. Попробуйте изменить параметры и повторить поиск заново.</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .main-container-trading {
    background-color: #6a6a6a;
    padding-left: 145px;
}


.container-modal-row {
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;

    padding: 80px 40px 50px 150px;
    margin-right: 146px;
}

.modal-row-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 83px;
}

.container-btn-params {
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 220px;

    border: 1px solid #c8b197;
    border-radius: 50px;

    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-btn-params:hover {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid #8a7565;
}

.btn-params-text {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;

    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.container-svg-icon-params {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.container-modal-window-selection-house {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 165px;

    width: 450px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.svg-icon-close-modal-window-selection-house {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 10px;

    border: none;
    background: transparent;

    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-window-selection-house {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.price-selection-house {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container-select-prices {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.input-label {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.from-to {
    margin-bottom: 3px;

    color: #b7b7b7;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    cursor: default;
}

.input {
    width: 170px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.hidden-filter-invalid-msg {
    display: none;
}

.filter-invalid-msg {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.square-selection-house {
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container-select-square {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container-btn-apply {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #c8b197;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-apply {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;

    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container-btn-reset {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;

    padding-top: 15px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden-btn-reset {
    display: none;
}

.btn-reset {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.container-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    max-width: 536px;
    background-size: cover;
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.item > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.item-details {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.model-house {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 49px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;

    transition: all 0.3s ease;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.model-house:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #c8b17a;
}

.container-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.price-house {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.size-house {
    color: #DE0D0D;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 78px;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container-buttons {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.btn-more-detailed {
    width: 150px;
    height: 55px;
    border: 3px solid #c8b197;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-style-more-detailed {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-more-detailed:hover .btn-style-more-detailed {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #c8b197;
    color: #000000;
}

.btn-presentation {
    background-color: #c8b197;
    width: 205px;
    height: 60px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-style-presentation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    gap: 10px;

    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.container-svg-icon-pdf {
    display: flex;
}


.container-show-all-houses {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 146px;

    padding-top: 40px;
    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    /*border-top: 1px solid #b0b0b0;*/
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
}

.show-all-houses {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;

    margin-bottom: 30px;

    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;

    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.show-all-houses:hover {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c8b197;
    color: #c8b197;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}


.no-results-message {
    padding: 40px 35px;
    margin-right: 146px;
    text-align: center;

    border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden-message {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
const allHouses = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'LOFTHAUS R70',
        price: 4465000,
        area: 70,
        img: 'https://topttedhbiu-dejlbfuh4uk.github.io/Layout_LoftHouse/images/item-1.jpg',

    },
// Добавьте тут ещё 10 домов, на меня кричат из-за спама
];

const containerBtnApplyEl = document.querySelector('.container-btn-apply');
const containerBtnResetEl = document.querySelector('.container-btn-reset');
const filterInputEls = [...document.querySelectorAll('.filter-input')];
const filterInvalidMsgEls = [...document.querySelectorAll('.filter-invalid-msg')];
const templateEl = document.querySelector('section > template');
const containerItemEls = document.querySelector('.container-items');

const addPointToNumber = (house) => {
    house.price = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU', {}).format(house.price).replace(/\s/g, '.');
};

const renderHouse = (house, index) => {
    const houseTemplate = templateEl.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

    if (index >= 9) {
        houseTemplate.classList.add('hidden');
    }

    houseTemplate.querySelector('img').src = house.img;
    houseTemplate.querySelector('.model-house').innerText = house.title;
    addPointToNumber(house);
    houseTemplate.querySelector('.price-house').innerText = `${house.price} ₽`;
    houseTemplate.querySelector('.size-house').innerText = `${house.area}м2`;

    containerItemEls.append(houseTemplate);
};

allHouses.forEach((house, index) => {
    renderHouse(house, index);
});

const showAllHousesEl = document.querySelector('.show-all-houses');
const hiddenHouseEls = [...document.querySelectorAll('.hidden')];
const containerShowAllHousesEl = document.querySelector('.container-show-all-houses');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('.container-show-all-houses > button');

showAllHousesEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hiddenHouseEls.forEach(hiddenHouse => {
        hiddenHouse.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    buttonEl.remove();
    containerShowAllHousesEl.classList.remove('container-show-all-houses');
});

const clearContainerItemEls = () => {
    [...containerItemEls.children].forEach(el => el.remove());
};

const getHouses = (filters) => {
    const response = allHouses.filter(house => {

        // house.price = house.price.replace(/\./g, '');
        // house.price = parseInt(house.price, 10);

        for (const filterKey in filters) {
            const filterVal = filters[filterKey];
            switch (filterKey) {
                case 'price': {
                    if (house.price < filterVal.from) return false;
                    if (house.price > filterVal.to) return false;
                    break;
                }
                case 'area': {
                    if (house.area < filterVal.from) return false;
                    if (house.area > filterVal.to) return false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
    return response.length ? response : null;
};

const isValidFilterInputEl = (filterInputEl) => {
    return !!filterInputEl.value || filterInputEl.value === 0;
};

const validateFilterInputEl = (filterInputEl) => {
    const isValid = isValidFilterInputEl(filterInputEl);
    filterInputEl.filterInvalidMsgEls.classList.toggle('hidden-filter-invalid-msg', isValid);
    return isValid;
};

filterInputEls.forEach((filterInputEl, index) => {
    filterInputEl.filterInvalidMsgEls = filterInvalidMsgEls[index];

    filterInputEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
        validateFilterInputEl(filterInputEl);
    });
});

const applyElClickHandler = () => {

    filterInputEls.forEach(filterInputEl => {
        if (!validateFilterInputEl(filterInputEl)) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    const filters = {};
    filterInputEls.forEach(filterInputEl => {
        const [filterKey, filterSubKey] = filterInputEl.id.split('-');
        const filter = filters[filterKey] = filters[filterKey] || {};
        filter[filterSubKey] = filterInputEl.value;
    });

    const houses = getHouses(filters);

    clearContainerItemEls();
    buttonEl.remove();
    containerShowAllHousesEl.classList.remove('container-show-all-houses');

    if (!houses) {
        const noResultsMessageEl = document.querySelector('.no-results-message');
        noResultsMessageEl.classList.remove('hidden-message');
        return false;
    }

    houses.forEach(house => {
        renderHouse(house);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас картинки имеют разную высоту. В связи с этим могут быть отличия в высоте карточек.

Размеры картинок на странице:
1 - 536x301.5
2 - 536x301.77
3 - 536x300.38 <- ниже остальных

Можно выровнять их высоту, например, добавлением обёртки для img в HTML:

```html
<div class="item-img-wrapper"> <!-- Добавялем wrapper -->
    <img src="" alt="item-1">
</div>
```

и заменой текущих стилей:

```css
.item > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

на следующие:

```css
.item-img-wrapper > img {
    width: 100%; /* меняем max-width на width для того, чтобы изображение максимально растягивалось */
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; /* для того, чтобы изображение вписывалось в обёртку */
}

.item-img-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%; /* чтобы изображение и обёртка были не шире родительского контейнера */
    aspect-ratio: 1.8;
}
```

`aspect-ratio` тут используется для установки равных пропорций для изображений. можно также заменить это свойство на явное указание высоты обёртки

Таким образом картинки на странице будут иметь равные пропорции.